# move TeXShop Preview `Drawer' to left or right side of viewer

Tags: mac, editors, texshop

[texshop](/questions/tagged/texshop)'s Previewer has a Drawer. On one of my computers it's on the left on another it is one the right. Can anyone tell me how to move it?

Teh Drawer is the overview thingy, inside the red frame, to the right on the Previewer in the screenshot (`file.tex` below for completeness)
[image: texshop preview]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
     \hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered = true}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\paragraph{Outline}
The remainder of this article is organized as follows.
Section~\ref{previous work} gives account of previous work.
Our new and exciting results are described in Section~\ref{results}.
Finally, Section~\ref{conclusions} gives the conclusions.

\section{Previous work}\label{previous work}
A much longer \LaTeXe{} example was written by \LaTeX

\section{Results}\label{results}
In this section we describe the results.

\section{Conclusions}\label{conclusions}
We worked hard, and achieved very little.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preview drawer position adjusts automatically relative to the space on the right or left of the preview window, and its position is remembered until there is no longer space on that particular side.  It's easiest the explain this with directions. Start with a preview window with no Drawer displayed.

1. Move the window so its left edge aligns with the left edge of your screen.
2. Open the Drawer: it will appear on the right of the window.

You can now move the window progressively to the right, and every time you open the Drawer it will still appear on the right, *until* you get to a point where there is no room to display the Drawer, and it will then flip to the left of the window.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm wondering if too innovative is a thing or I'm simply too manual.

Comment: Don't feel too bad, I'd never used the Drawer until I answered this question. :)

Comment: I use it constantly as kinda my _outlier-guideline_.